# SSRS How to use expression to display "Present" if it is '1900-01-01'?

Tags: reporting-services

Use expression to display "Present" if it is '1900-01-01'

[image]

I don't know how to set up a SWITCH or IIF function to accomplish this.

Comment: You would need to update the query that your parameter uses for the values with a check similar to RRichards' answer (though I assume your field is a DATE) - `CASE WHEN YEAR(DateField) = 1900 THEN 'Present' ELSE DateField END` .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the label in the dropdown for the date range parameter, this should do the trick.

```
=IIf(Right(Parameters!DateRange.Label, 4) = "1900", "Present", Parameters!DateRange.Label)
```